# Login with two steps / two forms (not meant 2-factor-auth!)

Tags: php, forms, web, authentication

Typical Login-Screens have one < form > element with two < input > (Username/Email and Passwort)

Since last year i see more and more "2 Step Logins". You first have type your username/email, submit the form and in next step you have to type your password and submit again.

1) Is there a name for this method?

2) Whats the main advantage of this technique?

Comment: This is not a good question on SO because it is not about a specific programming problem and 2) will yield opinionated answers.

Comment: I hope question 1) is at least specific enough - if a name for this technique exists. 
Advantages of question 2) can be pretty specific, too, imho.

Comment: To make life more miserable, especially for those using password managers. So we need to fumble with it twice...

Answer (score 2):

The one thing I often notice when I see this technique is a check to see if the username chosen is registered.

Getting a user to 'register' can be difficult. 'Registering' feels like a bit of a chore "Oh god I have to fill out a form and blah blah.

Getting a user to enter a name, and then checking if they are registered and if not having them enter a password twice is doing two things.

1. Making entrance seem easy, the word 'register' can be avoided entirely.
2. Breaking up the registration process into smaller steps and luring the user in to taking the first step "Well i've come this far!"

This method also allows a more seamless integration of single sign on. For example if the user enters a GoogleMail address, this is the perfect opportunity to hand them over to gmail SSO.

Of course there may be other reasons I've totally overlooked. But these seem like the stand out reasons to me.